# Alterar valor do objeto

Tags: javascript, angularjs, array

Tenho um array com objetos parecido com esse:

```
[{
        name: '2015',
        data: [...]
        color: 'orange'
    },
    {
        name: '2016',
        data: [...]
        color: 'red'
    }
]
```

Eu gostaria de mudar o valor de `name` para outro nome, tipo `MarketShare`, então ao invés do ano, eu teria um nome. Isso tudo tenho que fazer em *Javascript*

O resultado que eu espero é

```
[{
        name: 'marketshare',
        data: [...]
        color: 'orange'
    },
    {
        name: 'marketshare',
        data: [...]
        color: 'red'
    }
]
```

Comment: @LucasCosta Editei a pergunta

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode alterar acessando diretamente a chave:

```
meuArray[0].name = "MarketShare";
```

```js
var array = [{
  name: '2015',
  color: 'orange'
},
{
  name: '2016',
  color: 'red'
}];

array.forEach(item => {
  item.name = "Marketplace";
});

console.log(array);
```

O zero é o índice do array.

Answer (score 3):

Iterando o objeto e alterando o valor da propriedade o código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```js
var objeto = [
  { name: '2015', data: [], color: 'orange' },
  { name: '2016', data: [], color: 'red' },
];

objeto.forEach(function(item) {
  item.name = 'MarketShare';
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(objeto));
```

**Usando ES6**:

```js
const objeto = [
  { name: '2015', data: [], color: 'orange' },
  { name: '2016', data: [], color: 'red' },
];

const resultado = objeto.map((item) => ({ ...item, name: 'MarketShare' }));

console.log(JSON.stringify(resultado));
```

> [`Operador Spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)
>
> O operador spread permite uma expressão ser expandida em locais onde múltiplos argumentos (por chamadas de função) ou múltiplos elementos (por array literais) são esperados.

---

> [**Sintaxe de Espalhamento (Spread syntax)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).
>
> **Sintaxe de Espalhamento (Spread syntax)** permite um objeto iterável tal como uma expressão de array ou uma string ser expandida onde zero ou mais argumentos (para chamadas de funções) ou elementos (para arrays literais) são esperados, ou um objeto ser expandido onde zero ou mais pares propriedade:valor (para objetos literais) são esperados.
>
> ```
> function sum(x, y, z) {
>   return x + y + z;
> }
>
> const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
>
> console.log(sum(...numbers));
> // expected output: 6
>
> console.log(sum.apply(null, numbers));
> // expected output: 6
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira de se fazer usando apenas javascript, é iterar o objeto, criar uma nova propriedade e excluir a outra, veja no exemplo.

```js
var meuObjeto = [{
  name: '2015',
  color: 'orange'
}, {
  name: '2016',
  color: 'red'
}];

for (var i = 0; i < meuObjeto.length; i++) {
  meuObjeto[i]['MarketShare'] = meuObjeto[i]['name'];
  delete meuObjeto[i]['name'];
}

console.log(meuObjeto);
```

Comment: o seu código funciona, mas não é da maneira que preciso, acho que faltei com informações na pergunta. Dei uma editada, da uma olhada lá por favor.

Comment: A resposta do @LucasCosta responde sua pergunta então. :)